# Trirand jqGrid not showing up; TypeError: $(...).jqGrid is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jqgrid

Grid is not displaying, firefox console shows **"TypeError: $(...).jqGrid is not a function".**

**ASP.NET MVC 5.2.2 Razor,
jQuery 2.1.1, 
Trirand jqGrid 4.6.0**

I've checked other similar questions, each time the problem seems different and it's either syntax or import declarations problem. Mine seem fine. All referenced scripts are in place. Wrapping it in **$( document ).ready()** event doesn't make any difference.
Appreciate any help.

```js
<script type="text/css" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.sunny.min.css")">
</script>
<script type="text/css" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css")">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: "/Email/LoadDraftEmails/",
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: "GET",
            colNames: ["Id", "Subject", "Sender name", "Sender e-mail", "Created", "Last saved"],
            colModel: [
                { name: "ID", width: 50 },
                { name: "Subject", width: 200 },
                { name: "SenderName", width: 150 },
                { name: "SenderEmail", width: 150 },
                { name: "DateCreated", width: 150 },
                { name: "DateLatestSave", width: 150 }
            ],
            pager: "#pager",
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            sortname: "invid",
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            caption: "Draft emails"
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
    <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try putting `grid.locale-en.js` after `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that what you have shown is only a small portion of the entire HTML that gets rendered. Maybe there's the Layout which contains some other scripts that are mixing up.

To make sure that this is not the case, turn off the Layout temporary and have the entire markup in your view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/css" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.sunny.min.css")"></script>
    <script type="text/css" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#list").jqGrid({
                url: "/Email/LoadDraftEmails/",
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: "GET",
                colNames: ["Id", "Subject", "Sender name", "Sender e-mail", "Created", "Last saved"],
                colModel: [
                    { name: "ID", width: 50 },
                    { name: "Subject", width: 200 },
                    { name: "SenderName", width: 150 },
                    { name: "SenderEmail", width: 150 },
                    { name: "DateCreated", width: 150 },
                    { name: "DateLatestSave", width: 150 }
                ],
                pager: "#pager",
                rowNum: 100,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                sortname: "invid",
                sortorder: "desc",
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                autoencode: true,
                caption: "Draft emails"
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This should normally work as expected. If this is the case you should then see what script references might be getting mixed up in your Layout and ensure that the rendered page will look as shown here.

Comment: Done as you advised, grid showed up. Thank you so much, @Darin

Comment: @Lera: You have right to vote up to 30 answers or questions **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)), but you used it only once in 15 months. By using your voting right you gives tips for the searching engine and so help over people to find the information on the stackoverflow. So, please, use your voting right and vote up *all questions and answers which you find helpful*. You help other visitors of the page in the way.